# javascript empty string length equals to 2 instead of 0

Tags: javascript

In my ajax's success function , the returned response is a empty string (""), but when i try print out in console its length, it prints 2 as the length. How is this possible ? I am expecting for empty string length to 0 instead of 2. Has anyone have an idea ? Here is the snippet

```
success : function(response){
      if(response.indexOf("Error") === -1)
      {
            let name = response;
            console.log(name); //output in console is literaly ""
            console.log(typeof name, name.length) //output in console is "string 2"
      }

}
```

Comment: There are things such as non-printable characters. Try `Array.from(name, c => c.charCodeAt())` to see what character codes are in the string, then use an ASCII table to figure out what characters they are.

Comment: Are you sure your string is empty? It seems your string is literally `""`. Maybe your API encodes the response and wraps it with double quotes. And if it is empty, it returns only quotes.

Comment: It could be a two-byte unicode character that is some form of whitespace or the console is just not fit to show it.

Comment: I thing the API is wrapping the response with double quotes

Comment: @Xris so then it's a JSON-encoded empty string. You can use `JSON.parse(name)` to get the string you're expecting.

Comment: You're right, i should have parsed the response before. It is now printing length =  0 for empty string. I am going to post the response

Answer (score 1):

I should put JSON.parse() on response before checking the response type and length

```
success : function(response){
      if(response.indexOf("Error") === -1)
      {
            let name = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(name); //output in console is literaly empty
            console.log(typeof name, name.length) //output in console is "string 0"
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange. Try removing all white spaces from response

```
.replace(/ /g,'')
```

Try evaluate in console

```
name == ""
```

Unless you know that name is actually a string, you might end up causing problems for yourself by using the weak comparison. Fortunately, you can avoid this with judicious use of the strict equal (===) operator

```
name === ""
```